# Randomize products on the "home" or "index page" opencart

Tags: php, html, mysql, opencart

Been looking around and seen a few posts similar to my topic but none of the awnsers or question has an awnser to my specific question. I want to randomize the products displayed on the "home" or index page on my opecart website. These products are added by category into specific lists or modules. I cannot find any indication on where to do this for the specific modules that are displayed, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Which OC version?